# Why ":last" and ":last-child" does not work?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to select the last div with class `my_class` inside div with id `a`.
I tried several options with `:last` and `:last-child` but none of them worked.
[Here is on try.](http://jsfiddle.net/eU7By/2/)

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I faced a similar issue. I used .last() instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your selector works, you just weren't including jQuery in your fiddle, here's an updated/fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/eU7By/3/

On the left panel, make sure to select [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) as your library, by default it's [MooTools](http://mootools.net/) that's included...it is after all built by the MooTools guys :)

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

```
$("#a div.my_class:last");
```

[fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/eU7By/4/) -- oh and the reason your example wasn't working is because you had jsFiddle set to MooTools, not jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you selected MooTools instead of jQuery in the left hand options.